# Problems with linking .cpp files in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference

I'm having a headerfile called *cnVector.h* whose implementation is written in *cnVector.cpp*.
Those two files are located in the same directory.

```
cNormalCBP/
   + src/
       + cNormal/
           + cnUtils/
               - cnVector.h
               - cnVector.cpp
       - main.cpp
```

The header contains a simple class definition.

```
class cnVector {
    public:
        cnVector(double, double, double);

        inline cnVector cross(const cnVector&) const;
};
```

The implementation in the *.cpp* file is as follows:

```
#include "cnVector.h"
/* constructor */   cnVector::cnVector(double x, double y, double z)
        : x(x), y(y), z(z) {
}

cnVector cnVector::cross (const cnVector& vOther) const {
    return cnVector(
        y * vOther.z + z * vOther.y,
        z * vOther.x + x * vOther.z,
        x * vOther.y + y * vOther.x );
}
```

Now, the following code from *main.cpp* breaks at line **3** because of an *undefined reference to cnVector::cross(cnVector const&) const;*
Note how the constructor-implementation is recognized, but not the `cnVector::cross` method.

```
int main() {
    cnVector v1(1, 0, 0), v2(0, 1, 0);
    cnVector v3 = v1.cross(v2);
}
```

I also get an error-message *warning: inline function 'cnVector cnVector::cross(const cnVector&) const' used but never defined*.
Copying the implementation into *main.cpp* works.

> Can you explain to me why I can construct a *cnVector* instance but
>   the implementation of other methods are not recognized ?

Comment: "code from main.cpp breaks at line 3" -- by that you mean you get a linker error? Also are you sure you have cnVector.cpp listed in "Build target files" under "Build target tab" in "Project->Properties"? Finally can you post full main.cpp? Want to see #includes

Comment: Niklas, can you tell us what compiler/os you're using?  And is there any code that's been omitted here?  As I noted on the answer below, I cut-and-pasted your code and it works fine for me in VS 2010 on Win7.

Comment: @Joe Of course, sorry. *Win7 CyGWin GCC*. Yes there is omitted code, in the headerfile other method declarations and their implementation in the *.cpp* file as well as innecessary includes. In the *main.cpp* I missed the `#include cNormal/cNormal.h"`. *cNormal.h* basically includes *cnUtils.h* which includes *cnVector.h*.

Comment: @thekashyap Yes, I do. I didn't modify the settings, I also have rewritten the whole cnVector class already because of thid problem. I will take a look at the settings, thanks. (can't now) Will paste the whole main.cpp tomorrow

Comment: "I didn't modify the settings" -> In Code Blocks when you add a new cxx you should. Though it would ask you, when you add a cxx, which targets (Debug/Release/both) do you want to add new source file to and you just have to say yes. Though I feel TheBuzzSaw probably has the problem identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your inline functions to your header file. Inline functions need their entire definitions in the header files because of how they integrate with the rest of your code. The compiler will (maybe) attempt to insert the code at all locations where the function is called, so it needs to be visible in the header file similar to how templates need to be entirely present in the header file.

Comment: The inline keyword should allow the definition of the inline function in the .cpp file.  And in fact, when I cut-and-paste the code in the question into Visual Studio 2010, it compiles and executes just fine.

Comment: I use Code::Blocks and mingw myself. I got rid of all problems by placing the entire definitions in the header file. Personally, I don't recommend placing the implementation into the `.cpp` file. If it's a short function, it won't clutter things up in the header. If it's a long function, maybe it shouldn't be inline. :D

Comment: Can't say I disagree, and it should definitely make the problem disappear.  But I am very curious to why he/she's having the problem in the first place, since the code appears valid.

Comment: Before I knew about moving them to the header file, I would use the `inline` keyword in both places (prototype and definition). That *seemed* to make it behave, but I learned later about keeping it all in one place.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I have thought that the compiler could, elsewise to templates, insert the `object`-compiled code instead of the real C++ code. Thanks !